# Can this effect be created in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[image: color blur]

Was hoping someone had a tutorial on how to re-create this effect in adobe illustrator

Comment: You could but really you should be using photoshop

Comment: Welcome Jake! Is it *possible*? **Yes** - via blends and/or meshes rather easily. However, we aren't a "tutorial on demand" service. Questions should at least show *some effort* in solving your problem - what you've tried, where you are struggling, etc. You are asking others to expend effort to help you but are not showing anyone you are willing to make any effort yourself.

Comment: Much easier in Photoshop though, just [smudge the channels a bit](https://imgur.com/lD3hgOS)

Answer (score -2):

This is what I was able to create in Illustrator it gets pretty close.
[image]

Comment: Hello Jake. We welcome self-answers, it is a great way to show off the fact that sometimes one can figure out things for themselves. However, we DO require an actual answer, rather than just a screenshot of the result. Please [edit] your answer to show us _how_ you solved your problem and how others might be able to achieve the same result. Thanks for contributing!